# jQuery code breaks when changing tag from input to select

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a timesheet that I use jQuery to auto calculate the value between the start and stop times and then dynamically populate other input boxes based on the values from start and stop times. It was working fine until my boss wanted to change the start and stop times to only have 30 minute increments in them, so 7:00 AM, 7:30 AM etc. So since I don't know of a way to make the html tag of "time" increment by 30 min I just changed the input to a select and kept all the class names and field names the same and added the option values. The form still works, I get my values in all the boxes I want and it totals them up as well but now the values are not adding up correctly. If you select 8:00 AM in the start and 8:00 PM in the stop it totals 24 instead of 12. It seems to work up to around 10 hours then it falls apart. I've also just noticed going from something like 10:00 AM to 11:00 PM will only total 1 hour.
[Here is the fiddle:](http://jsfiddle.net/vegas/t2do5r0b/73/)
can someone tell me why it works fine when the field is an input but now that it's a select it falls apart?

```
//Event on change in START or STOP.
$(".start, .stop").on('change', function() {
//Look into $(this) to find the new TR group (row) with the class rowTR.
//This is dynamic and works for all ROWS modified
var start = $(this).parent().parent().find('.start').val().split(':');
var stop = $(this).parent().parent().find('.stop').val().split(':');
var hours1 = parseInt(start[0], 10) || 0;
hours2 = parseInt(stop[0], 10) || 0;
mins1 = parseInt(start[1], 10) || 0;
mins2 = parseInt(stop[1], 10) || 0;
var hours = hours2 - hours1,
    mins = 0;
if (hours < 0) hours = 24 + hours;
if (mins2 >= mins1) {
    mins = mins2 - mins1;
} else {
    mins = (mins2 + 60) - mins1;
    hours--;
}
mins = mins / 60; // take percentage in 60
hours += mins;
hours = hours.toFixed(2);
$(this).parent().parent().find('.hours').val(hours);
$(this).parent().parent().find('.dailyTotalGeneric').val(hours);
//Calculate all the daily total by row.
calculateWeeklyTotal()
});
$(".lunch").on('change', function() {
//get the value
var num = parseFloat($(this).parent().parent().find('.dailyTotalGeneric').val());
//If is checked, the lunch will be discount from hours.
if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    //Use newNum with discount of LUNCH
    $(this).parent().parent().find('.dailyTotalGeneric').val(num - 0.5);
} else {
    //else, add 0.5 to hours
    $(this).parent().parent().find('.dailyTotalGeneric').val(num + 0.5);
}
//Calculate the daily total again
calculateWeeklyTotal()
});

function calculateWeeklyTotal() {
var total = 0;
$('.dailyTotalGeneric').each(function() {
    total += ($(this).val() && !isNaN($(this).val())) ? parseFloat ($(this).val()) : parseFloat(0);
});
//Only 2 decimals
$('#total').val(total.toFixed(2))
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading your note to me in Chris Cousins' answer, I did a little research and found that it isn't at all difficult to get the time tag to display in half-hour increments. Just use the `step` attribute, so:

```html
<input type="time" step="1800">
```

The step amount has to be in seconds, so 1800 seconds for a half hour. [Here's](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/time) the doc on it, which may give you some other interesting ideas. Note that there are some caveats in the doc which suggest that there may be some issues using `step` in some browsers (seems to work fine in Chrome).

Comment: Thanks Bob, I'll give it a shot and see what happens. I notice right off the bat that it doesn't work in Edge but I'll see what I can do.

Comment: @Jason That's interesting. The doc says specifically that Edge supports the `step` attribute.

Comment: I say that because I used Edge to run the code snippet provided and there was no change. It still incremented 1 minute instead of 30.

Comment: @Jason no doubt. But if the doc specifically says it supports it, I wouldn't give up on it.

Answer (score 1):

Change the option values to 24hr format

```
<option value="00:00">12:00 AM</option>
<option value="00:30">12:30 AM</option>
<option value="01:00">1:00 AM</option>
<option value="01:30">1:30 AM</option>
...
<option value="22:30">10:30 PM</option>
<option value="23:00">11:00 PM</option>
<option value="23:30">11:30 PM</option>
```

then update the change function

```
$(".start, .stop").on('change', function() {
  //Look into $(this) to find the new TR group (row) with the class rowTR.
  //This is dynamic and works for all ROWS modified
  var start = $(this).parent().parent().find('.start').val().split(':');
  var stop = $(this).parent().parent().find('.stop').val().split(':');

  var hours1 = parseInt(start[0], 10) || 0;
  var hours2 = parseInt(stop[0], 10) || 0;
  var mins1 = parseInt(start[1], 10) || 0;
  var mins2 = parseInt(stop[1], 10) || 0;

  var startDate = new Date(0, 0, 0, hours1, mins1, 0);
  var endDate = new Date(0, 0, 0, hours2, mins2, 0);

  var diff = 0
  if (startDate < endDate) {
    diff = (endDate - startDate) / 36e5
  }

  //Apply changes dynamically, searching the main TR and looking into this to change the values of hours/dailyTotal inputs
  $(this).parent().parent().find('.hours').val(diff);
  $(this).parent().parent().find('.dailyTotalGeneric').val(diff);

  //Calculate all the daily total by row.
  calculateWeeklyTotal()
});
```

Comment: I was able to make it work with just changing the option values starting at midnight 00:00 up to 23:00 to 11:30 pm and it works like a charm. No need to change any of the jQuery code at all.  Thank you, I had a thought it might need to change to that but was stuck on the code having to be changed when in reality it didn't need to.

Answer (score 0):

Change the top part of your function,so that it splits the values with a space and then identifies **AM** or **PM**. For PM it adds 12 hours into the hour.

```
var startParts = $(this).parent().parent().find('.start').val().split(' ');
var start = startParts[0];
var startType = startParts[1];
var stopParts = $(this).parent().parent().find('.stop').val().split(' ');
var stop = stopParts[0];
var stopType = stopParts[1];

var hours1 = parseInt(start[0], 10) || 0;
hours2 = parseInt(stop[0], 10) || 0;
mins1 = parseInt(start[1], 10) || 0;
mins2 = parseInt(stop[1], 10) || 0;

if (startType == 'PM') {
  hours1+= 12;
}
if (stopType == 'PM') {
  hours2+= 12;
}
```

Comment: Alternatively, couldn't you avoid all this by changing the values to 0, .5, 1, 1.5, etc.?

Comment: Actually were a redesign in order, the values should simply represent number of minutes from midnight. So 30, 60, 90 and so on. That way the math is very simple and if you wanted to change to every 15 mins, the values just need to change, rather than the math in the function.

Comment: Number of minutes or number of hours? It might be that minutes is easier to change than hours, but you have to convert them to hours when you display the totals -- not that that's difficult. Either way, it seems to me from the OP's post that he is redesigning, so it might be good to consider getting rid of the strings and whacking all the parsing code.

Comment: @BobRodes a redesign is definitely in order as this was never meant to be what it is turning out to be. I have it working know thanks to Pavittar Gills partial answer below but what I would really prefer to happen is not use select at all and find a way to use the time tag in html5 and modify it to only display half hour increments.  I don't see that as a possibility right now so I may have to go with something like jQuery timepicker.

Comment: @jason You can easily do that, as it turns out. See my answer.